# What do the equipment stats do?

Tags: half-minute-hero

Each piece of equipment in the game seems to contribute some amount to each of the six stats. The icons look like a sword, a weight, a helmet, a target/crosshair, a boot, and a shield. What do each of these mean and how do they affect the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The six icons (with their pause screen names in parenthesis) are:

- Sword (Attack) - determines how much damage you deal
- Weight (Weight) - determines how fast you move, as well as how much knockback enemies do to you
- Armor (Defense) -  determines how much damage you take
- Bullseye (Hit) - determines your critical hit chance
- Boot (Speed) - determines your movement speed
- Shield (Evasion) - modifies the chance for enemies to score a critical hit

All of the stats, with the exception of weight, are also effected by your level - as you level up, your equipment stats mean less and less, and your level-up bonuses are worth a higher percentage.

Some bits of gear also have special attributes that may or may not be listed as part of these stats.

Comment: When you refer to movement speed under weight and boot, do you mean on the field, in battle, or both?

Comment: @murgatroid99, it is definitely speed in the field, and I'm fairly certain it also applies in battle. The battles are a little frenetic, so it's hard to say with 100% certainty.